# How to Change a C++ Class member's Type

Tags: c++, class, types, type-conversion, metaprogramming

Is it possible to be able to assign a "flexible" type to a class member? This would be somewhat like `std::variant` or `std::any`, except `std::variant` requires types to be stated in advance and `std::any` requires `any_cast<Type>` (which isn't a problem, except for saving the type information so I'd know what type to cast the `std::any` member to).

What I'm looking for is something that makes the following functionality possible:

```cpp
class FlexType
{
    ChangeableType m_Value;

public:
    FlexType(SomeType init_value) 
        : m_Value(init_value)
    {}

    void setValue(SomeOtherType new_value) { m_Value = new_value; }
    CurrentType getValue() const { return m_Value; }
};
```

**Edit**
I need the functionality for storing a return type of an `std::function`, where I want to be able to change the `std::function`'s return type to any given type. This comes from a class that has a `virtual void run() const` method (call it "ParentClass" for convenience). I then have a child class that overrides the `run()` method and runs an `std::function` and saves the return value in another class member.

It looks something like this:

```cpp
class ParentClass
{ // Example basic parent class
private:
    /* ... Class members ... */

public:
    ParentClass() = default;

    virtual void run() const { /* Do stuff w/ class members */ }
};

template<class FuncRetTy, class... FuncArgs>
class ChildClass : public ParentClass
{
private:
    using function_return_type = FuncRetTy;
    using function_arg_types = FuncArgs...;
    using function_args_container = std::tuple<function_arg_types>;
    std::function<function_return_type(function_args_container)>

    mutable function_return_type m_StoredValue;
    function_type m_Function;
    func_args_container m_Args;

public:
    FunctionMenu(
        function_return_type type_var, // Used to deduce return type
        function_type function,
        function_arg_types arguments)
        : m_Function(function)
        , m_Args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<FuncArgs>(arguments)...))
    {}

    void run() const override
    {
        m_StoredValue = m_Function(m_Args);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] function_return_type getStoredValue() const
    {
        return m_StoredValue;
    }

    // This is where my problem is...
    // I want to be able to set m_Function to another function,
    // but this means the return type can change, and so can
    // the tuple template parameters for m_Args.
    // The below code is just pseudocode
    template<class NewFuncRetTy, class... NewFuncArgs>
    void setFunction(
        NewFuncRetTy type_var,
        std::function<NewFuncRetTy(std::tuple<NewFuncArgs...>)> function
        NewFuncArgs... args)
    {
        // Change all class typedef's to new types
        // Reassign m_Function = function
        // Reassign m_Args = make_tuple(std::forward<NewFuncArgs>(args)...);
        // Delete whatever value m_StoredValue already has and 
        //     change type of m_StoredValue to NewFuncRetTy so
        //     getStoredValue() knows what type to return
    }
};
```

I'm sorry about there being a lot of code, but I figured explaining in detail what exactly I'm asking for would help people understand the question better.

Comment: Either the list of all possible types here is known, or it's not. If it's known, this is what std::variant is for. If it's not known, this is what std::any is for. There is no middle ground in C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Would you be willing to post an answer that showcases how to do this with `std::any`?

Comment: To do what, with `std::any`, exactly?

Comment: Just replace `ChangeableType` with `std::any` and your example would work. It's `getValue` you would have difficulty with; but you didn't ask for that to be possible.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik True, I will include that in my question. Is there a way to save the type information of `m_Value` for the `any_cast<T>`?

Comment: Your updated example would still compile if you replace `ChangeableType` with `std::any`. What is the problem with it?

Comment: This seems like an XY-problem. Why do you need such functionality? `std::any` can work, but so would a virtual type (and storing a pointer) or a template class that then has a static type bound. Either, of which, may be preferable to `std::any`.

Comment: @DrakeJohnson: "*except for saving the type information so I'd know what type to cast the `std::any` attribute to*" What does that mean? Who is "I" in this scenario, and how does "I" relate to the `any` object? C++ is a statically typed language, so the C++ code attempting to extract the value of the appropriate type needs to know what that type is. And by "know", I mean it must be written directly into the code somewhere; it cannot be determined at runtime.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh I added why specifically I'm asking this question.

Comment: @DrakeJohnson Why not make all return types either 1). derive from a common, virtual interface, or 2). be of a known subset of types so you can use a variant or tagged enum to access the proper type? `std::any` or a virtual interface now seems like a good use-case, but remember: C++ is statically typed, how languages like Python get around this is through virtual interfaces around a common object (like PyObject), or through a known subset of types.

Comment: It is not clear why you want to change the function. I am pretty sure you do NOT need that. Just instantiate another ChildClass with the other function, and replace that instance by the previous one.